R function of multiple arguments applied to only one variable
I know there is a very simple way to use apply on a function with multiple arguments where only one argument is the vector that the function is applied to, e.g. with a trivial example:
myfunction = function(x,y,z){
    return(x + y - z)
}

myvect = c(1,2,3,4,5)
sapply(myvect, myfunction(#,10,100))

The last line of code doesn't work, but I recall that there's something in place of # that can be used with apply and variations thereof that allows me to evaluate myfunction() over myvect with the y,z arguments are constants. I don't want to have to define myfunction with different y,z values every time I want to use sapply.
I suppose a naive way to do this is to use mapply with y,z as nrep(10,length(myvect)), nrep(100,length(myvect)), but I want to avoid this in favor of something more efficient.

mapply you already know about - you don't have to repeat the values though - mapply(myfunction, myvect, 10, 100)

Thanks, I didn't realize that I could use mapply with scalars rather than vectors.

In sapply the arguments slurped up by ... will be passed to the function so:
sapply(myvect, myfunction, 10, 100)

Optionally write it like this:
sapply(myvect, myfunction, y = 10, z = 100)

This also works.  Here partial will create a new function of one argument with y and z fixed at the indicated values.
library(purrr)
sapply(myvect, partial(myfunction, y = 10, z = 100) )

Another purrr solution is to use map_dbl in which case we can use formula notation for the function:
map_dbl(myvect, ~ myfunction(.x, 10, 100))

If we define myfunction with default values for y and z then as long as the defaults are ok we can just use an ordinary sapply:
myfunction2 = function(x, y = 10, z = 100) {
    return(x + y - z)
}

sapply(myvect, myfunction2)


Thanks, but I specifically wanted to avoid having to write a function with constant values so that I could vary these input arguments., so your first suggested solution is what I was looking for.
